# Why is this homotopy an isotopy?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology, calculus-of-variations

I am trying to follow the proof of  [Willem's quantitative deformation lemma](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=uGWaffeFbroC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q&f=false) and I get everything except the justification for the (iv) property which states:

> $\eta_t(u)$ is a homeomorphism for each $t\in [0,1]$.

I could see how if we restricted $\eta_t$ to $\overline{X\setminus A_2}$ then it would be a homeomorphism of $X$ because $\eta_t(u)=u$ for all $u\in \overline{X\setminus A_2}$. How about $A_2$?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be probably a thought failure it says "$\eta(t,\cdot)$ is a homeomorphism for every $t\in [0,1]$". This is crucial, beginning with the fact that $(4.2)$ is not stated for $t$ but $u$ and so forth.

Further the following error in the text may have brought confusion: $\psi$ shall be defined for $A_2$ and not $A_1$. Then the next equation for the corresponding case follows for $\phi$ on $A_2$ followed by the next equation (Cauchy) where follows for $\dot{w}$ the boundary $t\geq 0$. Herefrom the solution for $w$ that is defined on $[0,\infty[$.

Hence in your argumentation you are then right but keep in mind that only $\phi\equiv0$ not else. So due my understanding there is no other case.